# SilverStripe CMS times-out when changing pages in the CMS

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

I have installed SilverStripe on several servers successfully in the past (but I'm not a SilverStripe expert). This time my SS install fails to work and I'm at a loss how to fix it.

**The Problem**

- SilverStripe 2.4.6 installed correctly on the server (AFAIK).
- The front-end works as expected. (Show default theme. Pages all load correctly.)
- I am able to log into the CMS admin section succesfully. The CMS loads but when changing site pages in the CMS using the browser pane on the left, the CMS shows the circular loading symbol. The new page load never completes.
- Using the console of Firebug in Firefox - When attempting to change pages in the CMS (by clicking on the page browser pane) the CMS tries to load two pages. The second page request 404s. 
  [image: SilverStripe CMS with error.]
  The first GET request is from the initial page loads.
  The following POST+GET requests fire when clicking on the page tree to change pages.

**Attempting to Find the Solution**

I've tried deleting and re-installing silverstripe twice. (2.4.7 and 2.4.6) Both times the problem recurs.

A strange thing is that this server is already running two other silverstripe sites (both of which I installed without a hitch). All three websites are accessed via different domains. I tried accessing this install via another domain thinking there might be something wrong with how this third domain is configured but that didn't help either.

What should I try now? I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance.

**Responses to Comments**

> Check your root .htaccess file. Make sure RewriteBase is set to /

Checked. [Full .htaccess on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/p8NVrVE2)

> Indeed the javascrip URL is strange. Check if there is anything unusual about what's being returned from the previous POST request. Is the site running in dev, test or live mode?

I can't see anything unusual in the POST request.

*Clue Found:* The site is running in DEV mode. Switching to LIVE mode and the problem disappears. Also the second GET request only shows up in DEV mode.

[Example Post request with response](http://pastebin.com/2WqVbFLN). 
[Example Get request with respones](http://pastebin.com/R5nm6rj3).

Comment: the javascript call is strange: it says `javascrip` instead of `javascript`.  
i dont have this call here.
are there any modules installed?
you could also check if the encoding is utf8, just to make sure.

Comment: There are no modules installed. It's the default SS install. Where/how do I check the encoding?

Comment: Indeed the `javascrip` URL is strange. Check if there is anything unusual about what's being returned from the previous POST request. Is the site running in dev, test or live mode?

Comment: Check your root _.htaccess_ file. Make sure _RewriteBase_ is set to _/_

Comment: added responses to comment to question.

Comment: have you checked your server logs?

Comment: @outrunthewolf: Yes, checked the PHP and SS logs. Nothing stood out.

Comment: have you tried to manually clear the silverstripe cache? usually to be found at either
/tmp/silverstripe-cache-* or
/path/to/silverstripe/installation/silverstripe-cache or similar.

Comment: its wierd. Perhaps its a bug. Would you be interested in upgrading to version 3? Its a lot more stable and has better features

Comment: @schellmax: No, I didn't manually clear the cache. I'll give that a go.

Comment: @outrunthewolf: I can't upgrad to v3 in this case. I've built two other sites for the same client both using v2.4.

Comment: this is bugging me. Can you give us a more detailed shot of the full url being called, and the GET request and response?

Comment: @outrunthewolf: Just added example Post & Get responses to the question.

Comment: @TildalWave: I've just flushed the cache and set the cache-dir permissions to 777. No better.

Comment: @TildalWave: `mod_rewrite` is enabled. The frontend section of the website is working without a hitch and URL's are being rewritten to remove `index.php`. Even without mod_rewrite the CMS should still work. I don't have mod_rewrite enabled on my dev machine.

Comment: @TildalWave: `One of the proceeding requests fails to identify the name of the path it's referencing in the following AJAX/JS request due to this misconfiguration, thus the 404.` I'm being daft. I don't follow this comment. What path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a work around more than a fix but if you'd rather be coding than bug hunting it might be worth a go! (remember to log out of SS before doing this fix)

In your mysite/_config.php file change

```
Director::set_environment_type("dev");
```

to

```
if(!isset($_GET['isDev']))
   Director::set_environment_type("dev");
else
   Director::set_environment_type("live");
```

Then you can develop the website in dev mode normally and to use the admin in live mode and avoid the bug you just go to: **http://{your_domain}/admin?isDev=0**

N.B. might find a proper answer when pastebin.com isn't overloaded and I can see your responses!

Comment: No problem Shannon. Actually, I don't think the else statement is needed :-)